# How can I refresh embedded PHP code from the client side?

Tags: php, jquery, html

Basically, at the click of a button I need to refresh a div that contains embedded PHP. I tried using .html() in jQuery to reload the contents of the div, but it didn't change anything so I'm assuming it's not recalling the PHP (because the PHP should be changed at this point). It's probably just rewriting the HTML that was outputted by the PHP when the page loaded. I also tried appending something to the new HTML load so I could see it was at least refreshing the HTML code, and it was. It looked something like (if "updateObject" is a variable that contains the location of the div):

```
updateObject.html(updateObject.html() + " random text");
```

I also fiddled around with the .load() jQuery method, but it seemed to be for external PHP files (and at this point I can't change my embedded PHP to external PHP).

Any thoughts? Thanks!

EDIT: The biggest problem I've had is that, with my limited knowledge of web dev, I need to have the PHP embedded. If I make it a separate file, I'd have a very difficult time finding it because I honestly don't understand how the files get put together through the framework we're using (Drupal). I did try using an external PHP file but I couldn't figure out how to find it. Even if I put it in the same directory as this HTML file, it doesn't seem to be easy to find.

Comment: you can't, after php finishes executing, it returns a usable html document that javascript can manipulate and php is not fired again until a new page is loaded. If you need this functionality, you'll need to turn the service into an AJAX call, or refresh the page entirely

Comment: what does this `updateObject()` do? `.html()` expects to be passed a string of html.

Comment: also, what do you mean by "embedded" ??

Comment: The only way do to what you want to do (as far as I am aware) is to reload the page, which can be achieved with `location.reload(true);`. (The boolean specifies a forced reload from the server rather than the cache)

Answer (score 0):

You are to have 2 files:

**PHP**

This contains the data you want to show.

**HTML**

This is the one showing the php content.

In PHP you can put whatever you want. But the HTML once is loaded is loaded and the only way to have some more content into it is to make what is called an asynchronous call, which means a call after the page has been loaded.

To do this you are to use jQuery and call the $.post (or $.ajax), using this syntax:

```
$.post('filename.php', function(dataFromPhp){
    //actions to do once the php has been read
})
```

So in your case you can make a function that reads the php every time the click is done on a div/button/other DOM object; like so:

```
function updateDivContent(whatDiv){
    $.post('filename.php', function(dataFromPhp){
        if(dataFromPhp){
            $(whatDiv).html(dataFromPhp)
        }
    })
}
```

So if you want the div to be refreshed (and reload the php) you are to connect that function to an event and specify the div you want to show the data:

```
$('#myBtn').click(function(){
    updateDivContent('#myDiv');
})
```

Refer to this documentation for further informations: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/